# Spring Data JPA: Не запускается пример из книги Spring in action

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Пытаюсь запустить пример Spring Data JPA из 3 главы книги Spring in Action.
Проект добавил, как есть из примеров кода, ни чего не менял. Вот что выдает(делают в STS):

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-06-23 14:06:04.987
>   ERROR 6500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)

Здесь содержимое файла pom.xml maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::springDataJpa[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::springDataJpa[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Возможно нужны будут domen objects или еще что, напишите скопирую.

Пока на уровне выполнения примеров из книги, поэтому вообще не понимаю, в чем ошибка.

Как я понимаю, не получается создать bean с названием 'entityManagerFactory'? по причине того, что какой-то конструктор не получается создать.
Есть предположение, что надо что-то делать с версиями зависимостей hibernate.

UPDATE - SingleTableEntityPersister:

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
 * See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
 */
package org.hibernate.persister.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.access.EntityRegionAccessStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.access.NaturalIdRegionAccessStrategy;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.internal.DynamicFilterAliasGenerator;
import org.hibernate.internal.FilterAliasGenerator;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.MarkerObject;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.ArrayHelper;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Column;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Formula;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Join;
import org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Property;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Selectable;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Subclass;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Table;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Value;
import org.hibernate.persister.spi.PersisterCreationContext;
import org.hibernate.sql.InFragment;
import org.hibernate.sql.Insert;
import org.hibernate.sql.SelectFragment;
import org.hibernate.type.AssociationType;
import org.hibernate.type.DiscriminatorType;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

/**
 * The default implementation of the <tt>EntityPersister</tt> interface.
 * Implements the "table-per-class-hierarchy" or "roll-up" mapping strategy
 * for an entity class and its inheritence hierarchy.  This is implemented
 * as a single table holding all classes in the hierarchy with a discrimator
 * column used to determine which concrete class is referenced.
 *
 * @author Gavin King
 */
public class SingleTableEntityPersister extends AbstractEntityPersister {

    // the class hierarchy structure
    private final int joinSpan;
    private final String[] qualifiedTableNames;
    private final boolean[] isInverseTable;
    private final boolean[] isNullableTable;
    private final String[][] keyColumnNames;
    private final boolean[] cascadeDeleteEnabled;
    private final boolean hasSequentialSelects;

    private final String[] spaces;

    private final String[] subclassClosure;

    private final String[] subclassTableNameClosure;
    private final boolean[] subclassTableIsLazyClosure;
    private final boolean[] isInverseSubclassTable;
    private final boolean[] isNullableSubclassTable;
    private final boolean[] subclassTableSequentialSelect;
    private final String[][] subclassTableKeyColumnClosure;
    private final boolean[] isClassOrSuperclassTable;

    // properties of this class, including inherited properties
    private final int[] propertyTableNumbers;

    // the closure of all columns used by the entire hierarchy including
    // subclasses and superclasses of this class
    private final int[] subclassPropertyTableNumberClosure;

    private final int[] subclassColumnTableNumberClosure;
    private final int[] subclassFormulaTableNumberClosure;

    // discriminator column
    private final Map<Object, String> subclassesByDiscriminatorValue = new HashMap<Object, String>();
    private final boolean forceDiscriminator;
    private final String discriminatorColumnName;
    private final String discriminatorColumnReaders;
    private final String discriminatorColumnReaderTemplate;
    private final String discriminatorFormula;
    private final String discriminatorFormulaTemplate;
    private final String discriminatorAlias;
    private final Type discriminatorType;
    private final Object discriminatorValue;
    private final String discriminatorSQLValue;
    private final boolean discriminatorInsertable;

    private final String[] constraintOrderedTableNames;
    private final String[][] constraintOrderedKeyColumnNames;

    //private final Map propertyTableNumbersByName = new HashMap();
    private final Map<String, Integer> propertyTableNumbersByNameAndSubclass = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private final Map<String, String> sequentialSelectStringsByEntityName = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static final Object NULL_DISCRIMINATOR = new MarkerObject( "<null discriminator>" );
    private static final Object NOT_NULL_DISCRIMINATOR = new MarkerObject( "<not null discriminator>" );
    private static final String NULL_STRING = "null";
    private static final String NOT_NULL_STRING = "not null";

    //INITIALIZATION:

    public SingleTableEntityPersister(
            final PersistentClass persistentClass,
            final EntityRegionAccessStrategy cacheAccessStrategy,
            final NaturalIdRegionAccessStrategy naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy,
            final PersisterCreationContext creationContext) throws HibernateException {

        super( persistentClass, cacheAccessStrategy, naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy, creationContext );

        final SessionFactoryImplementor factory = creationContext.getSessionFactory();

        final Database database = creationContext.getMetadata().getDatabase();
        final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment = database.getJdbcEnvironment();

        // CLASS + TABLE

        joinSpan = persistentClass.getJoinClosureSpan() + 1;
        qualifiedTableNames = new String[joinSpan];
        isInverseTable = new boolean[joinSpan];
        isNullableTable = new boolean[joinSpan];
        keyColumnNames = new String[joinSpan][];
        final Table table = persistentClass.getRootTable();
        qualifiedTableNames[0] = determineTableName( table, jdbcEnvironment );

        isInverseTable[0] = false;
        isNullableTable[0] = false;
        keyColumnNames[0] = getIdentifierColumnNames();
        cascadeDeleteEnabled = new boolean[joinSpan];

        // Custom sql
        customSQLInsert = new String[joinSpan];
        customSQLUpdate = new String[joinSpan];
        customSQLDelete = new String[joinSpan];
        insertCallable = new boolean[joinSpan];
        updateCallable = new boolean[joinSpan];
        deleteCallable = new boolean[joinSpan];
        insertResultCheckStyles = new ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle[joinSpan];
        updateResultCheckStyles = new ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle[joinSpan];
        deleteResultCheckStyles = new ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle[joinSpan];

        customSQLInsert[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLInsert();
        insertCallable[0] = customSQLInsert[0] != null && persistentClass.isCustomInsertCallable();
        insertResultCheckStyles[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLInsertCheckStyle() == null
                ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLInsert[0], insertCallable[0] )
                : persistentClass.getCustomSQLInsertCheckStyle();
        customSQLUpdate[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLUpdate();
        updateCallable[0] = customSQLUpdate[0] != null && persistentClass.isCustomUpdateCallable();
        updateResultCheckStyles[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLUpdateCheckStyle() == null
                ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLUpdate[0], updateCallable[0] )
                : persistentClass.getCustomSQLUpdateCheckStyle();
        customSQLDelete[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLDelete();
        deleteCallable[0] = customSQLDelete[0] != null && persistentClass.isCustomDeleteCallable();
        deleteResultCheckStyles[0] = persistentClass.getCustomSQLDeleteCheckStyle() == null
                ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLDelete[0], deleteCallable[0] )
                : persistentClass.getCustomSQLDeleteCheckStyle();

        // JOINS

        Iterator joinIter = persistentClass.getJoinClosureIterator();
        int j = 1;
        while ( joinIter.hasNext() ) {
            Join join = (Join) joinIter.next();
            qualifiedTableNames[j] = determineTableName( join.getTable(), jdbcEnvironment );
            isInverseTable[j] = join.isInverse();
            isNullableTable[j] = join.isOptional();
            cascadeDeleteEnabled[j] = join.getKey().isCascadeDeleteEnabled() &&
                    factory.getDialect().supportsCascadeDelete();

            customSQLInsert[j] = join.getCustomSQLInsert();
            insertCallable[j] = customSQLInsert[j] != null && join.isCustomInsertCallable();
            insertResultCheckStyles[j] = join.getCustomSQLInsertCheckStyle() == null
                    ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLInsert[j], insertCallable[j] )
                    : join.getCustomSQLInsertCheckStyle();
            customSQLUpdate[j] = join.getCustomSQLUpdate();
            updateCallable[j] = customSQLUpdate[j] != null && join.isCustomUpdateCallable();
            updateResultCheckStyles[j] = join.getCustomSQLUpdateCheckStyle() == null
                    ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLUpdate[j], updateCallable[j] )
                    : join.getCustomSQLUpdateCheckStyle();
            customSQLDelete[j] = join.getCustomSQLDelete();
            deleteCallable[j] = customSQLDelete[j] != null && join.isCustomDeleteCallable();
            deleteResultCheckStyles[j] = join.getCustomSQLDeleteCheckStyle() == null
                    ? ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.determineDefault( customSQLDelete[j], deleteCallable[j] )
                    : join.getCustomSQLDeleteCheckStyle();

            Iterator iter = join.getKey().getColumnIterator();
            keyColumnNames[j] = new String[join.getKey().getColumnSpan()];
            int i = 0;
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
                Column col = (Column) iter.next();
                keyColumnNames[j][i++] = col.getQuotedName( factory.getDialect() );
            }

            j++;
        }

        constraintOrderedTableNames = new String[qualifiedTableNames.length];
        constraintOrderedKeyColumnNames = new String[qualifiedTableNames.length][];
        for ( int i = qualifiedTableNames.length - 1, position = 0; i >= 0; i--, position++ ) {
            constraintOrderedTableNames[position] = qualifiedTableNames[i];
            constraintOrderedKeyColumnNames[position] = keyColumnNames[i];
        }

        spaces = ArrayHelper.join(
                qualifiedTableNames,
                ArrayHelper.toStringArray( persistentClass.getSynchronizedTables() )
        );

        final boolean lazyAvailable = isInstrumented();

        boolean hasDeferred = false;
        ArrayList<String> subclassTables = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String[]> joinKeyColumns = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isConcretes = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isDeferreds = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isInverses = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isNullables = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isLazies = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        subclassTables.add( qualifiedTableNames[0] );
        joinKeyColumns.add( getIdentifierColumnNames() );
        isConcretes.add( Boolean.TRUE );
        isDeferreds.add( Boolean.FALSE );
        isInverses.add( Boolean.FALSE );
        isNullables.add( Boolean.FALSE );
        isLazies.add( Boolean.FALSE );
        joinIter = persistentClass.getSubclassJoinClosureIterator();
        while ( joinIter.hasNext() ) {
            Join join = (Join) joinIter.next();
            isConcretes.add( persistentClass.isClassOrSuperclassJoin( join ) );
            isDeferreds.add( join.isSequentialSelect() );
            isInverses.add( join.isInverse() );
            isNullables.add( join.isOptional() );
            isLazies.add( lazyAvailable && join.isLazy() );
            if ( join.isSequentialSelect() && !persistentClass.isClassOrSuperclassJoin( join ) ) {
                hasDeferred = true;
            }
            subclassTables.add(
                    join.getTable().getQualifiedName(
                            factory.getDialect(),
                            factory.getSettings().getDefaultCatalogName(),
                            factory.getSettings().getDefaultSchemaName()
                    )
            );
            Iterator iter = join.getKey().getColumnIterator();
            String[] keyCols = new String[join.getKey().getColumnSpan()];
            int i = 0;
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
                Column col = (Column) iter.next();
                keyCols[i++] = col.getQuotedName( factory.getDialect() );
            }
            joinKeyColumns.add( keyCols );
        }

        subclassTableSequentialSelect = ArrayHelper.toBooleanArray( isDeferreds );
        subclassTableNameClosure = ArrayHelper.toStringArray( subclassTables );
        subclassTableIsLazyClosure = ArrayHelper.toBooleanArray( isLazies );
        subclassTableKeyColumnClosure = ArrayHelper.to2DStringArray( joinKeyColumns );
        isClassOrSuperclassTable = ArrayHelper.toBooleanArray( isConcretes );
        isInverseSubclassTable = ArrayHelper.toBooleanArray( isInverses );
        isNullableSubclassTable = ArrayHelper.toBooleanArray( isNullables );
        hasSequentialSelects = hasDeferred;

        // DISCRIMINATOR

        if ( persistentClass.isPolymorphic() ) {
            Value discrimValue = persistentClass.getDiscriminator();
            if ( discrimValue == null ) {
                throw new MappingException( "discriminator mapping required for single table polymorphic persistence" );
            }
            forceDiscriminator = persistentClass.isForceDiscriminator();
            Selectable selectable = (Selectable) discrimValue.getColumnIterator().next();
            if ( discrimValue.hasFormula() ) {
                Formula formula = (Formula) selectable;
                discriminatorFormula = formula.getFormula();
                discriminatorFormulaTemplate = formula.getTemplate(
                        factory.getDialect(),
                        factory.getSqlFunctionRegistry()
                );
                discriminatorColumnName = null;
                discriminatorColumnReaders = null;
                discriminatorColumnReaderTemplate = null;
                discriminatorAlias = "clazz_";
            }
            else {
                Column column = (Column) selectable;
                discriminatorColumnName = column.getQuotedName( factory.getDialect() );
                discriminatorColumnReaders = column.getReadExpr( factory.getDialect() );
                discriminatorColumnReaderTemplate = column.getTemplate(
                        factory.getDialect(),
                        factory.getSqlFunctionRegistry()
                );
                discriminatorAlias = column.getAlias( factory.getDialect(), persistentClass.getRootTable() );
                discriminatorFormula = null;
                discriminatorFormulaTemplate = null;
            }
            discriminatorType = persistentClass.getDiscriminator().getType();
            if ( persistentClass.isDiscriminatorValueNull() ) {
                discriminatorValue = NULL_DISCRIMINATOR;
                discriminatorSQLValue = InFragment.NULL;
                discriminatorInsertable = false;
            }
            else if ( persistentClass.isDiscriminatorValueNotNull() ) {
                discriminatorValue = NOT_NULL_DISCRIMINATOR;
                discriminatorSQLValue = InFragment.NOT_NULL;
                discriminatorInsertable = false;
            }
            else {
                discriminatorInsertable = persistentClass.isDiscriminatorInsertable() && !discrimValue.hasFormula();
                try {
                    DiscriminatorType dtype = (DiscriminatorType) discriminatorType;
                    discriminatorValue = dtype.stringToObject( persistentClass.getDiscriminatorValue() );
                    discriminatorSQLValue = dtype.objectToSQLString( discriminatorValue, factory.getDialect() );
                }
                catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                    throw new MappingException( "Illegal discriminator type: " + discriminatorType.getName() );
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new MappingException( "Could not format discriminator value to SQL string", e );
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            forceDiscriminator = false;
            discriminatorInsertable = false;
            discriminatorColumnName = null;
            discriminatorColumnReaders = null;
            discriminatorColumnReaderTemplate = null;
            discriminatorAlias = null;
            discriminatorType = null;
            discriminatorValue = null;
            discriminatorSQLValue = null;
            discriminatorFormula = null;
            discriminatorFormulaTemplate = null;
        }

        // PROPERTIES

        propertyTableNumbers = new int[getPropertySpan()];
        Iterator iter = persistentClass.getPropertyClosureIterator();
        int i = 0;
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            Property prop = (Property) iter.next();
            propertyTableNumbers[i++] = persistentClass.getJoinNumber( prop );

        }

        //TODO: code duplication with JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

        ArrayList<Integer> columnJoinNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> formulaJoinedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> propertyJoinNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        iter = persistentClass.getSubclassPropertyClosureIterator();
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            Property prop = (Property) iter.next();
            Integer join = persistentClass.getJoinNumber( prop );
            propertyJoinNumbers.add( join );

            //propertyTableNumbersByName.put( prop.getName(), join );
            propertyTableNumbersByNameAndSubclass.put(
                    prop.getPersistentClass().getEntityName() + '.' + prop.getName(),
                    join
            );

            Iterator citer = prop.getColumnIterator();
            while ( citer.hasNext() ) {
                Selectable thing = (Selectable) citer.next();
                if ( thing.isFormula() ) {
                    formulaJoinedNumbers.add( join );
                }
                else {
                    columnJoinNumbers.add( join );
                }
            }
        }
        subclassColumnTableNumberClosure = ArrayHelper.toIntArray( columnJoinNumbers );
        subclassFormulaTableNumberClosure = ArrayHelper.toIntArray( formulaJoinedNumbers );
        subclassPropertyTableNumberClosure = ArrayHelper.toIntArray( propertyJoinNumbers );

        int subclassSpan = persistentClass.getSubclassSpan() + 1;
        subclassClosure = new String[subclassSpan];
        subclassClosure[0] = getEntityName();
        if ( persistentClass.isPolymorphic() ) {
            addSubclassByDiscriminatorValue( discriminatorValue, getEntityName() );
        }

        // SUBCLASSES
        if ( persistentClass.isPolymorphic() ) {
            iter = persistentClass.getSubclassIterator();
            int k = 1;
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
                Subclass sc = (Subclass) iter.next();
                subclassClosure[k++] = sc.getEntityName();
                if ( sc.isDiscriminatorValueNull() ) {
                    addSubclassByDiscriminatorValue( NULL_DISCRIMINATOR, sc.getEntityName() );
                }
                else if ( sc.isDiscriminatorValueNotNull() ) {
                    addSubclassByDiscriminatorValue( NOT_NULL_DISCRIMINATOR, sc.getEntityName() );
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        DiscriminatorType dtype = (DiscriminatorType) discriminatorType;
                        addSubclassByDiscriminatorValue(
                                dtype.stringToObject( sc.getDiscriminatorValue() ),
                                sc.getEntityName()
                        );
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                        throw new MappingException( "Illegal discriminator type: " + discriminatorType.getName() );
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new MappingException( "Error parsing discriminator value", e );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        initLockers();

        initSubclassPropertyAliasesMap( persistentClass );

        postConstruct( creationContext.getMetadata() );

    }
```

Comment: Можете добавить в ваш вопрос entity `SingleTableEntityPersister`

Comment: В ошибке есть строчка `Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister` -> проблема с созданием конструтора. Чтобы нам, ответчикам, это понять - нужно увидеть сущность (entity) `SingleTableEntityPersister`

Comment: Вот конструктор класса SingleTableEntityPersister: public SingleTableEntityPersister(
   final PersistentClass persistentClass,
   final EntityRegionAccessStrategy cacheAccessStrategy,
   final NaturalIdRegionAccessStrategy naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy,
   final PersisterCreationContext creationContext) throws HibernateException {

  super( persistentClass, cacheAccessStrategy, naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy, creationContext );

  final SessionFactoryImplementor factory = creationContext.getSessionFactory();

  final Database database = creationContext.getMetadata().getDatabase();

Comment: Простите, но я не могу разобрать, что у васнаписанно в комментарии. Добавьте нормально ваш конструктов в вопрос

Comment: Не влазил конструктор, удалил часть лога с ошибками. Все добавил начало модуля и весь конструктор класса.

Comment: Оу. Это класс часть hibernate. Я помню, что там был пример ресторана Taco. Извинете меня за мою невнимательность. Я посмотрел в кратце ту главу (на этой главе, кстати, я закончил читать книгу). Вам интересен код для работы JDBC? Я просто могу отдельно это вам написать... Он простой, но прилется Вам разбираться в нем

Comment: https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAuthenticationExample

Comment: JDBC это без использования JPA? Я имею ввиду, если вы помните в книге рассматривается два подхода для работы с реляционными бд: Spring Data JDBC и Spring Data JPA. У вас пример, когда вы читали книгу, с JPA запустился? P.S. Пример с JDBC у меня заработал, а вот с JPA нет. Я отложу вашу ссылку и посмотрю попозже, спасибо.

Comment: JDBC - это подключение к БД. JPA - Java Persistence API - мини-статейку прочтите в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). JPA - это ваши сущности, аннотации... Короче все, чтобы легко подсоединиться к БД.

Comment: Честно, я люблю использовать hibernate. Мне лень для пару объектов в БД прописывать сохранение, взятие объектов из бд, когда за тебя может это все сделать hibernate.

Comment: Полезная ссылка (надеюсь) на аннотации. В случае, если что-то не понравится/непоймете - в интернете неплохо по спрингу и hibernate рассказывают сайты https://www.baeldung.com и https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/

Comment: Может я дам не самый лучший совет, но вы быстрее освоете hibernate + spring практикуя самому. Я выучил буквально основы spring (как я говорил, на той 3 главе я закончил читать книгу) и дальше начал сам пытаться создавать проект. Лучшей практикой будет написать обычную авторизацию на сайт: адресы, телефоны, ФИО... Примером тому может служить та ссылка выше.

Comment: Книгу я рекомендую больше как справочник использовать, нежели опору в изучении spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Пример необходимо запускать, либо с Java 8, либо обновить Spring Boot до долее новой версии? чтобы использовать с Java 12, например:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: оуууу... Вот в чем была ошибка. Да, parent - это важно)